# Authenticate user on local LDAP directory with forward to remote directory if local lookup fails

Tags: proxy, ldap

We have a situation where we deploy hardware appliances that consist of several servers onto our customer sites.  These appliances include in internal (replicated) openLDAP server that manages the users, group and sudoers information used for authentication and authorization onto and between the appliance servers.  Not all of the servers have direct access to network interfaces outside of the appliance boundaries.

We have a situation where we need to be able to first authenticate against the entries on the local servers, and if a user isn't found in the local directory, then forward the request to an external directory service (such as AD).

I see a lot of information about pass-through proxy and similar techniques but we aren't interested in passing through all of the requests, just the ones that fail locally.